# SAP RFC command using sap.connector.dll

Tags: .net, saprfc

Would like to seek your help and ask the command to use to initiate and call an RFC function.

I have downloaded the file sap.connector.dll and make use of it.  I browse the net and I cannot find or do the SAP component.  Is there a way to just execute a command?

Comment: Have you read the documentation available at http://service.sap.com/connectors? It contains an excellent introduction as well as the complete API reference.

Comment: thank you so much vwegert, however i do not have access to that site. :( i don't have user and password.. :(

Comment: i just downloaded the sap.connector.dll in the internet, but i believe there is a complete installation of that version.  Hope you dont mind me asking a copy from you if you have.  Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: As far as I know that would be a violation of the license, besides being off-topic on SO...

Comment: thank you vwegert.. so sad to know... :(

Comment: @LiraCruz, as vwegert mentioned there is documentation available at the site below, but there is not any login required. I just tried, and can download the "programming guide" without any credentials: https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/msnet.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..
I'm using these DLLs for this which comes with SAP Connector

- rscp4n.dll
- sapnco.dll
- sapnco_utils.dll

If you need to call an SAP transaction using these connection details you can try this..

```
public void ExecuteTransaction(string tCode, string input)
        {
            int sub = 0;
            try
            {
                tCode = "YOUR Transaction Code";
                RfcConfigParameters rfc = new RfcConfigParameters();
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Name, "BOXName");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "HOST");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SAPRouter, "YOUR ROUTER STRING");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "CLIENT");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.UseSAPGui, "1");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "SAP USERNAME");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "PW");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "SYS NUMBER");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
                rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");

                //rfc.Add(RfcConfigParameters.IdleCheckTime, "0");

                RfcDestination rfcDest = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination(rfc);
                //rfcDest.Ping();
                RfcRepository rfcRep = rfcDest.Repository;



                IRfcFunction funcArtikel =  rfcRep.CreateFunction("ABAP4_CALL_TRANSACTION");
                //IRfcTable itab = funcArtikel.GetTable("SPAGPA_TAB");
                funcArtikel.SetValue("TCODE", tCode);
                funcArtikel.SetValue("MODE_VAL", "A");
                funcArtikel.SetValue("UPDATE_VAL", "A");
                funcArtikel.SetValue("SKIP_SCREEN", "X");
                //itab.Append();
                //itab.SetValue("PARID", "PARAMETER NAME");
                //itab.SetValue("PARVAL", VALUE);
                //funcArtikel.SetValue("SPAGPA_TAB", itab);
                funcArtikel.Invoke(rfcDest);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.ToString();
                //throw ex;   
            }
        }
```

And here I've commented some code because it is used to get some values ( set of data ) from SAP using RFC Table if you need you can enable them also.

And don't change the following code set. It is the default SAP transaction for the RFC calls.You can change whatever the TCODE you need.

```
 IRfcFunction funcArtikel =  rfcRep.CreateFunction("ABAP4_CALL_TRANSACTION");
                    //IRfcTable itab = funcArtikel.GetTable("SPAGPA_TAB");
                    funcArtikel.SetValue("TCODE", tCode);
                    funcArtikel.SetValue("MODE_VAL", "A");
                    funcArtikel.SetValue("UPDATE_VAL", "A");
                    funcArtikel.SetValue("SKIP_SCREEN", "X");
```

And if you retrieving some data using IrfcTable you may need to convert IRfcTable to DataTable for that you can use this..

```
public static class IRfcTableExtentions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts SAP table to .NET DataTable table
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sapTable">The SAP table to convert.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DataTable ToDataTable(this IRfcTable sapTable, string name)
        {
            DataTable adoTable = new DataTable(name);
            //... Create ADO.Net table.
            for (int liElement = 0; liElement < sapTable.ElementCount; liElement++)
            {
                RfcElementMetadata metadata = sapTable.GetElementMetadata(liElement);
                adoTable.Columns.Add(metadata.Name, GetDataType(metadata.DataType));
            }

            //Transfer rows from SAP Table ADO.Net table.
            foreach (IRfcStructure row in sapTable)
            {
                DataRow ldr = adoTable.NewRow();
                for (int liElement = 0; liElement < sapTable.ElementCount; liElement++)
                {
                    RfcElementMetadata metadata = sapTable.GetElementMetadata(liElement);

                    switch (metadata.DataType)
                    {
                        case RfcDataType.DATE:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name).Substring(0, 4) + row.GetString(metadata.Name).Substring(5, 2) + row.GetString(metadata.Name).Substring(8, 2);
                            break;
                        case RfcDataType.BCD:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetDecimal(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                        case RfcDataType.CHAR:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                        case RfcDataType.STRING:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                        case RfcDataType.INT2:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetInt(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                        case RfcDataType.INT4:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetInt(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                        case RfcDataType.FLOAT:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetDouble(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                        default:
                            ldr[metadata.Name] = row.GetString(metadata.Name);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                adoTable.Rows.Add(ldr);
            }
            return adoTable;
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much tarzanbappa..   I have tried to use those dll and we are encountering "grant authorization on rfc_metadata" just upon loging in to the SAP... which we do not know yet how to resolve.. :( but i think it has something to do with SAP configutation.. am i right?  the problem also, we need to settle it without disturbing the client.. (

Comment: You may need to grant rfc permissions to SAP User account

Comment: You can uncomment the `rfcDest.Ping();` and debug to check whether your connection to SAP is success or not

Comment: thank you so much again... i will try it out.. :) sorry for i will be disturbing you a lot on this... :) hope you dont mind... :)

Comment: by the way, do you have alternative like using sap.connector.dll ? when connecting and calling rfc function? coz we might not able to asn client to grant permission. :(

Comment: check this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18187/SAP-connector-for-Microsoft-NET 
but its in VB

Comment: thank you so much again.. :) very appreciate the help.. i will check it out..  i've tried the ping and it gave me "Expression has been evaluated and has no value" result..

Comment: sorry to bother you... just wanted to ask if you have a sample command in SAP.Connector that can help me execute an SAP function? in example, i would like to execute the function "Z_M_MXTD_MAT_LESEN_SC"

Comment: sorry, may i know what is TCode?

Comment: i need to create a program that will call SAP function.  previously i have but it is using powerbuilder program and using librfc32.dll..

Comment: my boss wanted me to convert that program using .net and sap.connector.dll but i have no idea using it  :(

Comment: I have a code on connection, i able to connect.. but after that, i have no idea already... :(

Comment: destination = New SAP.Connector.Destination()
destination.AppServerHost = APPSERVER
destination.Client = CLIENT
destination.SystemNumber = SYSNUM
destination.Username = USER
destination.Password = PW
destination.Language = LANGUAGE
destination.LogonGroup = "PUBLIC"
destination.MsgServerHost = APPSERVER
destination.Trace = True

session = New SAP.Connector.SAPConnection(destination)
session.Open()

Comment: Hi T Code is you Transaction Code (SAP Function Name)

Comment: Is this Z_M_MXTD_MAT_LESEN_SC a SAP transaction code??

Comment: I have mentioned how to execute a SAP function in my answer.. You can replace following line like this and check..
`funcArtikel.SetValue("TCODE", "Z_M_MXTD_MAT_LESEN_SC");`

Comment: hI, I tried the script you have and there is no problem using the 3 dll's mentioned by you.  but I encounter the error "User Z003ATZD has no RFC authorization for function group RFC_METADATA."  and it is not possible for us to ask the client for authorization. because of that, we need to shift to different dll and its sap.connector.dll.  I have the connection script but i dont know how to start or initiate and process the T code.. :(

Comment: may i know if there is a way to resolve the authorization issue without the need to ask our client?  thank you in advance for the great help.